# Turning Off Validation of Editor Template

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, validation

Following on from my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30703228/mvc-validation-on-subviews)

I still find myself with a bit of a validation problem.

So I have a custom editor template for addresses.  The model is annotated with validation rules.

On one view I have 2 instances of an address editor, one for billing address and another for shipping address (if it is different).  I also have a checkbox the user can select if the addresses are the same.

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Billing)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.UseBillingForShipping) 
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Delivery)
```

If the user checks the checkbox some JavaScript copies the billing to the delivery and the view validates fine.  However, if the user checks the checkbox before entering the billing address I have a problem.

I know I could run the JavaScript on lost focus of each control of the billing address but what I would like to do is turn off the validation of the delivery editor template if the checkbox is checked then deal with the copying of address in the controller. Is this possible?

Comment: Rather than copying the address, perhaps use a `[RequiredIfFalse]` attribute so that validation occurs only if the checkbox is not checked. Then in the POST method copy the billing address to the delivery address if that's necessary to store in the database

Comment: you won't be able to change to editor template to make this work. The editor templates are simple Razor views, the code is execute before rendering the page. You'll have to do js magic or server side magic

Comment: @StephenMuecke on the CreateUser model I have 2 addresses and a boolean field for DevilerySameAsBilling.  Are you saying I could annotate the billing address here with `[RequiredIfFalse("Delivery")]` and that would override the annotation on the address model?

Comment: Yes it will. It means that if the checkbox is unchecked, then `Delivery` must be completed by the user, but if its checked, the user can leave it blank (there will be no validation error). And then rather that copying the address, your script might just disable `Delivery` if checked (and set it to an empty string). The actual usage is `[RequiredIfFalse("UseBillingForShipping", ErrorMessage="...")]` applied to the `Billing` property.